# Vue Component Vue-Instant

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I just installed vue-instant to make an auto suggestion for search and get an example code like this

https://jsfiddle.net/santiblanko/dqo6vr57/

My question is how to move components `'vue-instant': VueInstant.VueInstant` to a new Vue component like this one:

```
Vue.component('vue-instant-component', {
  //vue-instant
}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
Vue.component('vue-instant', {
  data: {
    value: '',
    suggestionAttribute: 'original_title',
    suggestions: [],
    selectedEvent: ""
  },
  methods: {
    clickInput: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'click input'
    },
    clickButton: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'click button'
    },
    selected: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'selection changed'
    },
    enter: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'enter'
    },
    keyUp: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'keyup pressed'
    },
    keyDown: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'keyDown pressed'
    },
    keyRight: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'keyRight pressed'
    },
    clear: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'clear input'
    },
    escape: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'escape'
    },
    changed: function() {
      var that = this;
      this.suggestions = [];
      axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=342d3061b70d2747a1e159ae9a7e9a36&query=' + this.value)
        .then(function(response) {
          response.data.results.forEach(function(a) {
            that.suggestions.push(a)
          });
        });
    }
  }
})
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you just want to avoid the `components` block at the end of your fiddle, you can call `Vue.component('vue-instant', VueInstant.VueInstant);` before constructing the `Vue` instance to register it.

Comment: @Botje, it give me `suggestionAttribute is not defined`

Comment: Then I'm lost as to what you are trying to do. Are you trying to create a new component that extends `VueInstant` with some defaults?

Comment: @Botje I just want to move the example above to the form `Vue.component ()` . The code should not in `new Vue()` but in `Vue.component ()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I slightly misunderstood the question, below is the original answer.

This is how you might turn the code above into a component:

```
Vue.component("movies",{
  template:`
    <div>
      {{selectedEvent}}
      <vue-instant :suggestion-attribute="suggestionAttribute" v-model="value" :disabled="false"  @input="changed" @click-input="clickInput" @click-button="clickButton" @selected="selected"  @enter="enter" @key-up="keyUp" @key-down="keyDown" @key-right="keyRight" @clear="clear"  @escape="escape" :show-autocomplete="true" :autofocus="false" :suggestions="suggestions" name="customName" placeholder="custom placeholder" type="google"></vue-instant>
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      value: '',
      suggestionAttribute: 'original_title',
      suggestions: [],
      selectedEvent: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickInput: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'click input'
    },
    clickButton: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'click button'
    },
    selected: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'selection changed'
    },
    enter: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'enter'
    },
    keyUp: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'keyup pressed'
    },
    keyDown: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'keyDown pressed'
    },
    keyRight: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'keyRight pressed'
    },
    clear: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'clear input'
    },
    escape: function() {
      this.selectedEvent = 'escape'
    },
    changed: function() {
      var that = this
      this.suggestions = []
      axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=342d3061b70d2747a1e159ae9a7e9a36&query=' + this.value)
        .then(function(response) {
        response.data.results.forEach(function(a) {
          that.suggestions.push(a)
        })
      })
    }
  },
  components: {
    'vue-instant': VueInstant.VueInstant
  }
})
```

**Original answer**

> I just want to move the example above to the form Vue.component () . The code should not in new Vue() but in Vue.component ()

If I understand correctly, the syntax you are looking for is

```
Vue.component('vue-instant', VueInstant.VueInstant)
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqo6vr57/114/).

Comment: It work when i placed it on `<div id="app">` . But when I put inside a component error occurs

Comment: @AbidRakhmansyah Did you want to include all those handlers in the component?

Comment: Right :) Thank you sir!